# WPF: Frame to receive data within a ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I need a part of my `Page` unmovable, so I thought using a `Frame`, something like:

```
<StackPanel>
     <Label Style="{StaticResource OneThirdColumnLabel}">Administrar papéis: Alterar papéis</Label>
         <ItemsControl x:Name="PapeisIc">
             <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                      <Frame x:Name="_papeisAddFrame" Source="PapeisAdd.xaml" Height="50"/>
                  </DataTemplate>
              </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

Then, the `Frame` would contain a `Page` with:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,10">
            <Label Style="{StaticResource LaterLabel}">Papel:</Label>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Papel}" Style="{StaticResource StdTextBox}" Width="100" />
            <Label Style="{StaticResource LaterLabel}">Descrição:</Label>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Descricao}" Style="{StaticResource StdTextBox}" Width="400" />
            <Button x:Name="DeleteFieldBtn" Style="{StaticResource deleteFieldButtom}" ToolTip="Eliminar este papel"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

In the code-behind, the line:

```
PapeisIc.ItemsSource = _papeis;
```

Binds a object that's an `ObservableCollection` of 3 items and I need it to display the 3 elements in the example.

What I get is:

[image]

So that, somehow it knows that there are 3 elements, but it doesn't bind it right...

I already tried to pass to the `Page` the data as a parameter, but it didn't work either.

How can I bind those values?

Just to make it clear, I'm trying to bind to an `ObservableCollection` of:

```
public class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Papel { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Frame` control does not pass the `DataContext` down to the `Page`. The easiest way to solve this issue is to remove the `Frame` and move its content directly to the `DataTemplate`.

If you really need the `Frame`, you have to listen to the `LoadCompleted` and `DataContextChanged` events and propagate the `DataContext` manually to the content of the `Frame`. I show you how to do it with a `TriggerAction` using the `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf` NuGet package.

```
public class UpdateContentDataContextAction : TriggerAction<Frame>
{
   protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
   {
      if (AssociatedObject.Content is FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
         frameworkElement.DataContext = AssociatedObject.DataContext;
   }
}
```

```
<DataTemplate>
   <Frame x:Name="_papeisAddFrame" Source="PapeisAdd.xaml" Height="50">
      <b:Interaction.Triggers>
         <b:EventTrigger EventName="LoadCompleted">
            <local:UpdateContentDataContextAction/>
         </b:EventTrigger>
         <b:EventTrigger EventName="DataContextChanged">
            <local:UpdateContentDataContextAction/>
         </b:EventTrigger>
      </b:Interaction.Triggers>
   </Frame>
</DataTemplate>
```

If you want to do it in the code-behind, subscribe the events on the control and use the code of the trigger action.

```
<Frame x:Name="_papeisAddFrame" Source="PapeisAdd.xaml" Height="50" LoadCompleted="OnLoadCompleted" DataContextChanged="OnDataContextChanged">
```

```
private void OnLoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
   PropagateDataContext((Frame)sender);
}

private void OnDataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
   PropagateDataContext((Frame)sender);
}

private void PropagateDataContext(Frame frame)
{
   if (frame.Content is FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
      frameworkElement.DataContext = frame.DataContext;
}
```